# Gradient decent

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to perform gradient decent in data set with binary target variable flag_bad and iam facing many problems with %do statement and updating the parameters value

```
%let learning_rate=.01;
%let max_iterations=2;
%let iterations = 0;
%let convergence = 0;

/*%macro test ;*/ %LET alpha = 0;
%LET beta1 = 0;
%LET beta2 = 0;
%LET beta3 = 0;
%LET beta4 = 0;


%do %while (&iterations < &max_iterations);

data gradiant;
    set out_SOC.New_Socio_Score(keep=score_WOE_REGION_Desc 
        score_WOE_Sector_PQR_Final Activity_Years1 CL_TO_60 pd flag_bad);
    alpha=&alpha;
    beta1=&beta1;
    beta2=&beta2;
    beta3=&beta3;
    beta4=&beta4;
    pd_prod=(1 / (1 + exp(-(&alpha + &beta1 * score_WOE_REGION_Desc + &beta2 * 
        score_WOE_Sector_PQR_Final + &beta3 * Activity_Years1 + &beta4 * CL_TO_60))));
run;

PROC SQL;
    SELECT SUM(FLAG_BAD, PD_PROD)*alpha AS alpha_GRAD, 
    SUM(FLAG_BAD, PD_PROD)*beta1 AS beta1_GRAD, 
    SUM(FLAG_BAD, PD_PROD)*beta2 AS beta2_GRAD, 
    SUM(FLAG_BAD, PD_PROD)*beta3 AS beta3_GRAD, 
    SUM(FLAG_BAD, PD_PROD)*beta4 AS beta4_GRAD 
    FROM gradiant;
QUIT;

/* Update coefficients using gradient descent */
alpha=%EVAL(&alpha + &learning_rate * &alpha_GRAD);
beta1=%EVAL(&beta1 + &learning_rate * &beta1_GRAD);
beta2=%EVAL(&beta2 + &learning_rate *&beta1_GRAD);
beta3=%EVAL(&beta3 + &learning_rate * &beta2_GRAD);
beta4=%EVAL(&beta4 + &learning_rate * &beta3_GRAD);
iterations=%EVAL(&iterations + 1);

%end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to perform gradient descent to update coefficients for a logistic regression model with binary target variables. However, I notice a few issues in your code. Here are some suggestions to address them:

1. In your SQL code, you're trying to use SUM with a comma between variables (e.g., `SUM(FLAG_BAD,PD_PROD)`). Instead, you should use the plus operator to sum these variables: `SUM(FLAG_BAD + PD_PROD)`. Make this change for all the SUM statements.
2. There's a missing `%macro` statement at the beginning, but it's commented out (`/%macro test ;/`). If you intend to create a macro, uncomment this line, and add an appropriate `%mend` statement at the end of your code.
3. It seems there's an issue with variable naming in the update coefficients section. For example, `&beta1_GRAD` is used to update `beta1`, but it should be `&beta1_GRAD` for consistency.
4. The SQL code is calculating gradient values, but it doesn't update the coefficients in the original dataset. You need to replace the coefficients in your original dataset with the updated values after each iteration.

Here's an updated version of your code with these issues addressed:

```
%let learning_rate = 0.01;
%let max_iterations = 2;
%let iterations = 0;
%let convergence = 0;

%macro gradient_descent;
%let alpha = 0;
%let beta1 = 0;
%let beta2 = 0;
%let beta3 = 0;
%let beta4 = 0;

%do %while (&iterations < &max_iterations);
    data gradiant;
        set out_SOC.New_Socio_Score(keep = score_WOE_REGION_Desc score_WOE_Sector_PQR_Final Activity_Years1 CL_TO_60 pd flag_bad);
        pd_prod = 1 / (1 + exp(-(&alpha + &beta1 * score_WOE_REGION_Desc + &beta2 * score_WOE_Sector_PQR_Final + &beta3 * Activity_Years1 + &beta4 * CL_TO_60)));
    run;

    PROC SQL;
        SELECT SUM(FLAG_BAD + PD_PROD) * &alpha AS alpha_GRAD,
               SUM(FLAG_BAD + PD_PROD) * &beta1 AS beta1_GRAD,
               SUM(FLAG_BAD + PD_PROD) * &beta2 AS beta2_GRAD,
               SUM(FLAG_BAD + PD_PROD) * &beta3 AS beta3_GRAD,
               SUM(FLAG_BAD + PD_PROD) * &beta4 AS beta4_GRAD
        FROM gradiant;
        QUIT;

    /* Update coefficients using gradient descent */
    %let alpha = %eval(&alpha + &learning_rate * alpha_GRAD);
    %let beta1 = %eval(&beta1 + &learning_rate * beta1_GRAD);
    %let beta2 = %eval(&beta2 + &learning_rate * beta2_GRAD);
    %let beta3 = %eval(&beta3 + &learning_rate * beta3_GRAD);
    %let beta4 = %eval(&beta4 + &learning_rate * beta4_GRAD);

    iterations = %eval(&iterations + 1);
%end;

/* At this point, your updated coefficients are in &alpha, &beta1, &beta2, &beta3, and &beta4 */
%mend gradient_descent;

/* Call the macro to perform gradient descent */
%gradient_descent;
```

This code should help you perform gradient descent and update the coefficients correctly. Make sure to call the `gradient_descent` macro to execute the gradient descent iterations.

Comment: Where is alpha_grad coming from in that %let statement? Link between the data set and macro variable creation seems missing in both code?

Comment: I have updated the code with the following " data coef; a = sum(&alpha ,- &learning_rate * mean(alpha_GRAD)); s = sum(&beta1 ,- &learning_rate * mean(beta1_GRAD)); d = sum(&beta2, - &learning_rate * mean(beta2_GRAD)); f = sum(&beta3 ,- &learning_rate * mean(beta3_GRAD)); g = sum(&beta4 ,- &learning_rate * mean(beta4_GRAD)); i = &iterations + 1; run; data coefagg; run; data coefagg; set coefagg coef; run; %let alpha = coef.a[0]; %let beta1 = coef.s[0]; %let beta2 = coef.d[0]; %let beta3 = coef.f[0]; %let beta4 = coef.g[0]; %let iterations = coef.i[0]; %end ;" and not working again

Comment: Simply i want to update the  new coefficients values using values from table coef

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: Error: Data step component object failure, Aborted during the compilation phase.

Comment: Error: invalid object or method name